Inverse Compton effect and the maximum energy of the scattered photon
If we have say a proton which is moving at constant velocity (considerable fraction of the speed of light) in some direction with initial momentum $p_i$ and collides with a low energy, $h\nu_0$, photon, we can always rotate the frame of reference in order for the proton's velocity direction to lie on the $x$ axis. As such, I'm guessing the conservation of energy and momentum relations for the collision would be
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{Conservation\ of\ energy:}\\
&h\nu_0+\sqrt{m_p^2c^4+p_i^2c^2}=h\nu+\sqrt{m_p^2c^4+p_f^2c^2}\\
&\mathbf{Conservation\ of\ momentum:}\\
&\mathsf X: \frac{h\nu_0}{c}\,\cos\theta+p_i=\frac{h\nu}{c}\cos\varphi+p_f\cos\phi\\
&\mathsf Y:\frac{h\nu_0}{c}\,\sin\theta=\frac{h\nu}{c}\sin\varphi-p_f\sin\phi
\end{align}
where we consider the collision diagram as the incident photon coming from the lower-left quadrant at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the $x$ axis, the scattered photon with energy $h\nu$ being ejected at the top-right quadrant at an angle $\varphi$ with respect to the $x$ axis, and the proton being redirected with a momentum $p_f$ towards the lower-right quadrant at an angle $\phi$ with respect to $x$ axis after the collision. Of course, if we permit the angles to go from $0$ to $2\pi$ these directions and signs can be fixed in order for the conservation equations to hold.
Question: If those relations are true, when is it that the ejected photon acquires the maximum energy?
Attempt/My argument: For the ejected photon to acquire the maximum energy, as seen from the conservation of energy, we need to maximize $\nu$,
$$h\nu=\underbrace{h\nu_0+\sqrt{m_p^2c^4+p_i^2c^2}}_{\text{fixed/constant}}-\sqrt{m_p^2c^4+p_f^2c^2},$$
and this happens when the momentum of the proton after colliding is $0$, namely, when $p_f=0$. If we do so and solve for $\nu$ in terms of $\theta$ we get
$$\frac{\nu}{\nu_0}=1-\frac{p_ic\cos\theta}{m_pc^2-h\nu_0}$$
For $\nu$ to be maximum we need $\theta=\pi$, but it yields a lower energy than expected, since in the inverse Compton effect case the ejected photon is usually more energetic than the incident one.
In light of this I thought about approaching it differently: deriving the formula for inverse Compton effect and then applying the extremal values. To derive it I thought about looking at the collision in the frame of reference of the proton because it means it is at rest and thus we can use the usual Compton effect formula. The thing is you need to use the relativistic Doppler effect to compute the new frequencies and also you need to account for relativistic aberration of the angles so I couldn't manage to derive it... Any ideas?

I think it's much simpler here to use the (what I think is) more standard way, namely using the conservation law of the four momenta as vectors. The reason is that the four momentum squared $\mathbf{p}$ of any single localized particle satisfies $\mathbf{p}^2=-m^2$ where $m$ is the particle's mass, and where I am using natural units, so $c=1$.
We can write the four momenta for this problem starting with the most general form, before collision we have:
$$ \mathbf{p}_\gamma = (E_\gamma , E_\gamma \hat{n}_\gamma), \ \mathbf{p}=(E, p\hat{n}_p) $$
Where subscript $\gamma$ indicates photon quantities and we write no subscript for the proton quantities.
So that, after collision we have, using primes:
$$ \mathbf{p}_\gamma' = (E_\gamma^{'}, E_\gamma^{'}\hat{n}_\gamma'), \ \mathbf{p}'=(E^{'},p'\hat{n}'_p) $$
Now conservation of four momentum gives:
$$ \mathbf{p}_\gamma + \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{p}_\gamma'+\mathbf{p}' $$
Since we're not interested in the state of the proton post scattering we can isolate it on the LHS, so it will be gone once we square the equation:
$$ \mathbf{p}' = \mathbf{p}_\gamma + \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{p}_\gamma' $$
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{p}'^2 = -m_p^2 &= \left(\mathbf{p}_\gamma + \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{p}_\gamma' \right)^2
\\&= \require{cancel}\cancel{\mathbf{p}_\gamma^2} + \mathbf{p}^2 + \cancel{\mathbf{p}_\gamma'^2} + 2\mathbf{p}_\gamma\mathbf{p}-2\mathbf{p}_\gamma\mathbf{p}_\gamma'-2\mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}_\gamma'
\\ &= -m_p^2  + 2\mathbf{p}_\gamma\mathbf{p}-2\mathbf{p}_\gamma\mathbf{p}_\gamma'-2\mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}_\gamma'
\\ &= -m_p^2 - 2E_\gamma E + 2E_\gamma E_\gamma^{'} + 2E E_\gamma^{'} + 2E_\gamma p (\hat{n}_\gamma\cdot \hat{n}_p) - 2E_\gamma E_\gamma^{'} (\hat{n}_\gamma \cdot\hat{n}_\gamma') - 2pE_\gamma^{'} (\hat{n}_p\cdot \hat{n}_\gamma')
\end{align*}
Now cancelling the $-m_p^2$ and isolating $E_\gamma^{'}$ we find:
$$ E_\gamma^{'}\left( 2E_\gamma + 2E - 2E_\gamma (\hat{n}_\gamma \cdot \hat{n}_\gamma') - 2p(\hat{n}_p\cdot\hat{n}_\gamma') \right) = 2E_\gamma E - 2E_\gamma p (\hat{n}_\gamma\cdot \hat{n}_p)   $$
$$ E_\gamma^{'} = \frac{E_\gamma E - E_\gamma p (\hat{n}_\gamma\cdot \hat{n}_p)}{E_\gamma- E_\gamma(\hat{n}_\gamma \cdot \hat{n}_\gamma') + E  - p(\hat{n}_p\cdot\hat{n}_\gamma')}  $$
Looking at the numerator, we see that to maximize it we can require: $\hat{n}_\gamma\cdot \hat{n}_p=-1$, which means that the collision is head-on. Now to minimize the denominator, $- p(\hat{n}_p\cdot\hat{n}_\gamma')$ is more important than $- E_\gamma(\hat{n}_\gamma \cdot \hat{n}_\gamma') $ because in the inverse compton scattering the charged particle is much more energetic than the photon by assumption. Therefore we require $\hat{n}_p\cdot\hat{n}_\gamma' = 1$, which together with our first condition immediately implies $\hat{n}_\gamma \cdot \hat{n}_\gamma' = -1 $. The equation thus becomes:
$$E_\gamma^{'} = \frac{E_\gamma( E +  p)}{2E_\gamma + E  - p}  $$
I think this is actually the standard result for the maximum energy of the photon in this effect, which can be further developed by approximations such as:
$$ p = \sqrt{E^2-m^2} \approx E - \frac{m^2}{2E} $$
etc.

Thank you, Amit. I asked my professor about this problem too and suggested your solution is correct as something similar appears in a previous final exam. The main issue right now is the numerical solutions do not concur with your expression; I'm sure the mistake isn't yours because your explanation and derivation was impeccable!

Glad to be of help. I'm not sure what you mean by the numerical solutions, after all this expression is for the maximum energy, if you mean compared to experiment, the scattered photon will always gain a lower energy in general. Also, perhaps the difficulty is due to the use of natural units, the above expression is more useful when masses and energies are in $\text{MeV}$ so that $c=1$ isn't an issue

Sorry for keeping you on hold, Amit. As I said, your result is more than correct. The numerical solution discrepancy was finally solved: it was a matter of units (joules and eV) and using the wrong rest energy for the proton. The original problem gave values for the energy of the photon and the moment of inertia of the photon and the results I got weren't the ones shown in the solution sheet.

It's all good, glad you found the discrepancy in the calculation.  Incidentally, "moment of inertia" is related to rotation usually, I think you meant just the momentum, cheers.

Yes, sorry, I had a lapsus...
